Проблемы при удалении библиотеки grpc
У меня после запуска кода Go, связанного с grpc, выходит:
# google.golang.org/grpc/internal/resolver/dns ..\..\..\Go\pkg\mod\google.golang.org\grpc@v1.67.1\internal\resolver\dns\dns_resolver.go:39:2: could not import google.golang.org/grpc/internal/resolver/dns/internal (EOF)
# google.golang.org/grpc/balancer/pickfirst ..\..\..\Go\pkg\mod\google.golang.org\grpc@v1.67.1\balancer\pickfirst\pickfirst.go:32:18: could not import google.golang.org/grpc/internal/grpclog (EOF)
# google.golang.org/grpc/internal/transport ..\..\..\Go\pkg\mod\google.golang.org\grpc@v1.67.1\internal\transport\controlbuf.go:33:2: could not import google.golang.org/grpc/internal/grpclog (EOF) ..\..\..\Go\pkg\mod\google.golang.org\grpc@v1.67.1\internal\transport\http2_client.go:47:11: could not import google.golang.org/grpc/internal/syscall (EOF) ..\..\..\Go\pkg\mod\google.golang.org\grpc@v1.67.1\internal\transport\http2_client.go:49:2: could not import google.golang.org/grpc/keepalive (EOF)

Я хочу попробовать удалить библиотеку grpc (использую VS Code) и установить обратно, но когда я удаляю папку grpc вручную, VS Code создаёт папку обратно.

добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! как задать хороший вопрос

Если я правильно понял про удаление, стоит не только папку grpc удалять, но и связанные зависимости в go.mod и go.sum, а затем заново устанавливать через go get.
